# sifr3 line height issue

Tags: sifr

Why is it that the line height of the last line of text (in any quote with 3 or more lines) is greater than the line height of the above lines?

The issue is replicable at www.UXQuotes.com

Answer (score 0):

Because Flash is weird. Now that doesn't help much, but Flash text rendering does have a few issues…